# hair dynamic not working on certain mesh

Tags: modeling, particles, hair, dynamic

I'm having an issue with hair dynamic. I'm using blender 2.9 and I've noticed if I use any other object and apply hair dynamics (like a sphere or a cube) it works with no problem. But with the mesh I'm using for my character, the dynamics refuse to work.

Nothing happens at all when I hit play, the hair stays stiff. I used a human gen plugin to make the mesh and it's weird cause when I use their custom made hairs and turn on dynamics, it works with no problem. I'm so confused and I don't know what the problem is.

What my mesh with dynamic on looks like next to a sphere with dynamics on. Nothing happens with the human mesh, only the sphere.

[image: screenshot human sphere]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7px7xyygno5ed9/ME%203.blend?dl=0

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot and give details so we can understand what is this question about? *Which* hair particle system does not work? *Which mesh* do you mean? The file you provided contains 2 human models. The visible one has only two particle systems: eyelashes and eyebrows. The -hidden- backup model has additionally two hairstyles. None of the hairsystems is dynamic.

Comment: Here is an image of what my mesh with dynamic on looks like next to a sphere with dynamics on. Nothing happens with the human mesh, only the sphere
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbemsuedtzkj0xd/unknown.png?dl=0

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot and the file update! In the screenshot, the *[_] Hair Dynamics* are not enabled for the human model (particle system *ParticleSettings*). Had you ticked the checkbox when you tested it? I've tried with your file and it works for me when I enable the Hair Dynamics (Blender 2.93.6)

Comment: that is so weird that it's working now cause before I had it enabled but it did nothing. I went back and grabbed an old file that has the dynamic on and it's still not working. But one thing I noticed when I tried adding hair in the particle editor, the dynamic don't work. So like when I try to add a whole new particle system and try to make frizzy hairs and turn on the dynamics, it doesn't work